# gameclosure native-android debug failed local.properties file not found

Tags: android, gameclosure

I am getting the following error while trying to run

```
devkit debug native-android
```

ERROR

```
BUILD FAILED
                /home/bonnie/adt/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:597: The following error occurred while executing this line:
                /home/bonnie/GameEngines/MyGameClosure/modules/devkit-core/modules/native-android/TeaLeaf/build.xml:7: Source resource does not exist: /home/bonnie/GameEngines/MyGameClosure/modules/devkit-core/modules/native-android/TeaLeaf/local.properties
```

looking closely I found the local.properties fille is missing.
How can i fix this? what is the reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy the local.properties file 
from 
build/debug/native-android/local.properties 
to  
modules/devkit-core/modules/native-android/TeaLeaf/

```
cp build/debug/native-android/local.properties modules/devkit-core/modules/native-android/TeaLeaf/
```

-OR-

 change line no. 7 of

```
modules/devkit-core/modules/native-android/TeaLeaf/buid.xml
```

to

```
<loadproperties srcFile="../../../../../build/debug/native-android/local.properties" />
```

`